# Establishing Root Widget / accessing it as app.root?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

What step(s) am I missing in establishing "MyKivyRoot' as my root widget in the files below?

I was under the impression that the top/left-most widget in the .kv file would automatically be treated as the root widget.  But obviously I've missed some essential step.

Using "app.root.show_text()" doesn't seem to point to the right place (I get a "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'show_text'" error).

But I CAN access the method from within the < MyKivyRoot > block using "root.show_text()"

What am I forgetting to do here?

Here's a simplified version of my 'main.py':

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class MyKivyRoot(BoxLayout):
    def show_text(self):
        return "Here is your text"

class NewClass(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MyKivyApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyKivyApp().run()
```

And here's 'MyKivy.kv'

```
MyKivyRoot:

<MyKivyRoot>:
    Label:
        text: root.show_text()
    NewClass

<NewClass>:
    Label:
        text: app.root.show_text()
```

I've been working through the "Creating Apps with Kivy" book and having no problems with the code in the book (I have experience with PySide).  But when I tried to experiment on my own I got stumped right away by this basic (I assume) problem.  As far as I can see, I have it laid out identically to the (working) code from the book, but clearly there's something I'm overlooking.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a root widget.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''
<MyKivyRoot>:
    Label:
        text: root.show_text()
    NewClass

<NewClass>:
    Label:
        text: app.root.show_text() if app.root else ''

# The first two just define classes, they don't create instances:
MyKivyRoot:
# This does
'''


class MyKivyRoot(BoxLayout):
    def show_text(self):
        return "Here is your text"


class NewClass(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MyKivyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyKivyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare child widgets inside of the root widget declaration. Angle bracket notation is used to define widgets but they must also be declared. User defined variables must be declared inside the widget definition in order that they can be passed as arguments on widget declaration.

```
#untitled.kv#

Screen:
    FooWidget:
        name: 'World'
        size_hint: 1, .5
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
    BarWidget:
        color: 1, .5, 0
        size_hint: 1, .5
        pos_hint: {'y': 0}

<FooWidget@Label>:
    name: ''
    text: f'Hello, {self.name}'

<BarWidget@Widget>:
    color: 0, 0, 0
    canvas.before:
        Color: 
            rgb: root.color
        Rectangle:
            pos: root.pos
            size: root.size

-------------------------------------
#untitled.py#

from kivy.app import App

class UntitledApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    UntitledApp().run()
```